# Removing nulls and empty objects of mixed data types from a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

How would one go about cleaning a dictionary containing a variety of datatypes of nulls and empty lists, dicts etc. E.g.

```
raw = {'key': 'value', 'key1': [], 'key2': {}, 'key3': True, 'key4': None}
```

To:

```
refined = {'key': 'value', 'key3': true}
```

Because of the mixed nature of data types in the dictionary, using:

```
refined = {k:v for k,v in processed.items() if len(v)>0}
```

throws a

> TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()

Is there a solution to make a second conditional based on `type(v) is bool`?

Edit: I've found the issue I was encountering employing solutions was a result of the structure of the data, asking a separate question to deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
refined={k:v for k,v in raw.items() if v or isinstance(v,bool)}
```

---

```
raw={'key': 'value',
 'key1': [],
 'key2': {},
 'key3': True,
 'key4': None,
 'key5': False}
refined={k:v for k,v in raw.items() if v or isinstance(v,bool)}
#{'key': 'value', 'key3': True, 'key5': False}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
refined = {k:v for k, v in processed.items() v is not None and (type(v) not in (list, dict) or len(v) > 0)}
```